# How to improve this JavaScript code to make it more portable?

Tags: javascript, portability

The following is a little JavaScript project to display quotes on a web page. Since I want to use it in a number of different web sites, I read up on good practices for making portable JavaScript code, e.g.:

- use no global variables
- use namespaces
- make it easy to plugin
- use default values which can be overridden

For those of you who have experience writing JavaScript libraries and portable JavaScript code, **what could be improved on this code to (a) make it more portable, (b) avoid any unforeseen problems or conflicts, (c) improve the naming conventions, etc.?**

**index.htm:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>smart quotes</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/smartquotes.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                SMARTQUOTES.init();
                SMARTQUOTES.quotes = new Array(
                'It\'s tempting to augment prototypes of built-in constructors such as Object(), Array(), or Function(), but it can seriously hurt maintainability.',
                'We come from XHTML backgrounds, so we will close all tags, use lowercase, and use quotation marks around attributes.',
                'Checking to see if a value exists inside an array is always a bore in JavaScript.',
                'JavaScript classes have the same effect on some people that garlic has on Dracula.',
                'Mixins are not supported natively by CoffeeScript, for the good reason that they can be trivially implemented yourself.',
                'Using a single var statement at the top of your functions is a useful pattern to adopt.',
                'Using the Function() constructor is as bad as eval()',
                'Any obstacle that I\'ve encountered during my development by placing JavaScript at the bottom of the page has been easily overcome and well worth the optimization gains.'
                );
                SMARTQUOTES.duration = 8000;
                SMARTQUOTES.start();
            };
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            div#quoteWrapper {
                border: 1px solid #999;
                padding: 10px;
                background: #eee;
                color: navy;
                width: 300px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                font-style: italic;
                font-family: arial;
                font-size: 12pt;
                text-align: center;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="quoteWrapper">
        <div id="SMARTQUOTE"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**smartquotes.js:**

```
(function(global) {
    var SMARTQUOTES = {};
    if(global.SMARTQUOTES) {
        throw new Error('SMARTQUOTES has already been defined');
    } else {
        global.SMARTQUOTES = SMARTQUOTES;
    }
})(typeof window === 'undefined' ? this : window);  

SMARTQUOTES.init = function() {
    SMARTQUOTES.quoteIndex = 0;

    SMARTQUOTES.duration = 3000;

    SMARTQUOTES.quotes = new Array();
    SMARTQUOTES.quotes[0] = 'test quote #1';
    SMARTQUOTES.quotes[1] = 'this is the second quote';
    SMARTQUOTES.quotes[2] = 'and now the third and last quote'; 

    SMARTQUOTES.element = $('div#SMARTQUOTE').hide();

    SMARTQUOTES.incrementQuote = function() {
        SMARTQUOTES.quoteIndex++;
        if(SMARTQUOTES.quoteIndex >= SMARTQUOTES.quotes.length) {
            SMARTQUOTES.quoteIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    SMARTQUOTES.displayQuote = function () {
        var quote = SMARTQUOTES.quotes[SMARTQUOTES.quoteIndex];
        SMARTQUOTES.element.fadeOut('slow', function() {
            SMARTQUOTES.element.html(quote);
        });
        SMARTQUOTES.element.fadeIn();
        SMARTQUOTES.incrementQuote();
        SMARTQUOTES.startTimer();
    }

    SMARTQUOTES.startTimer = function () {
        var t = setTimeout('SMARTQUOTES.displayQuote()', SMARTQUOTES.duration);
    }

    SMARTQUOTES.start = function() {
        SMARTQUOTES.displayQuote();
    }

}
```

Comment: could be a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: `'Using the Function() constructor is as bad as eval()'` using strings in setTimeout is even worse

Comment: thanks didn't know about codereview beta yet, reposted there to check out the traffic there: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12020/how-to-improve-this-javascript-code-to-make-it-more-portable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ideas (I'll add more later):

- You could replace the first part (global) with a

> var SMARTQUOTES = SMARTQUOTES || {};

- You could add an optional "element" in your init. Something like:

> ```
> SQ.init = function (elem) {     
>   if (elem === undefined) {     
>     elem = 'div#SMARTQUOTE';     
>   }     
>   // ...     
>   SQ.element = $(elem).hide();     
>   // ...
> ```

- Maybe enclose it all in a self-executing block:

> ```
> (function (){
>   var SMARTQUOTES = SMARTQUOTES || {};
>   SMARTQUOTES.init = function (elem) {
>   ...
>   }
> }());
> ```

- Even better, use this keyword

> ```
> (function (){
>   var SMARTQUOTES = SMARTQUOTES || {};
>   SMARTQUOTES.prototype.init = function (elem) {
>      var that = this;
>      that.index = ...
>   ...
>   }
>   SMARTQUOTES.prototype.displayQuote = function() {
>      that.startTimer(); ...
>   }
> }());
> ```

- Read [this](http://shichuan.github.com/javascript-patterns/) and [this](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) article.
  They are about module patterns.